# Mongo details are not showing in phpinfo() in windows

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am installing mongodb on my windows 7 PC. I have installed mongodb 3.0 along with the necessary drivers & tried starting mongo server, it is working well but when i open the localhost & check for the phpinfo page, it does not show me the details of mongo. I also am using Umongo client for database interaction where i am not able to create database manually. It is just because of this? Where is the problem?. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please read this document to add php_mongo.dll services in php 5.3 and later

For adding mongo db in php you need to add php_mongo.dll in your wamp directory 
Example:

> c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext

Document: https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/